# Understanding Connection pool with JMX related properties

Tags: tomcat, jmx, tomcat-jdbc

I am analyzing JMX mbean (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.jmx.ConnectionPool) properties for my jdbc datasource related properties and I needed some reference on what these properties means. I couldn't find any documentation on what these methods give. I Checked https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/jmx/ConnectionPool.html#getActive() and couldn't find any info.

```
getActive()
getIdle()
getSize()
getWaitCount()
```

Is these have any connection with Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool properties mentioned in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html? what is the relationship between Active Idle and Size (seems like Active + Idle = Size).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods on that MBean just delegate [directly to the pool implementation](https://github.com/wjw465150/TomcatJDBCPool/blob/master/lib/tomcat-jdbc-src/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/ConnectionPool.java):

- `getActive()`: number of established connections that are being used by the application
- `getIdle()`: number of established connections not being used
- `getSize()`: number of established connections to the database
- `getWaitCount()`: number of threads waiting for a connection